# Why three informations are needed to describe the orientation of a body? (plus other questions)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have a fixed system of coordinates $O→(x,y,z)$, that from now on will be called `world frame`, and a body $P$ representing an aircraft whose coordinates in this system are $(P_x, P_y, P_z)$.

In the body $P$ is recognized a relative system of coordinates $O'→(P,R,Y)$. The `Roll axis` points from the origin towars the nose of $P$, the `Pitch axis` points toward the right of $P$, the `Yaw axis` points toward the bottom. At the beginning the body was orientated with the nose of the body in the same direction of the $y$ versor, but now is oriented otherwise.

My goal is to describe the position of a second body $Q=(Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$ into the coordinates system of the body $P$ using the conventions most used with aircrafts.
If $C$ is a change of coordinates, the $x$ axis must be sent into the $P$ axis, the $y$ axis must be sent into the $R$ axis, the $z$ axis must be sent into the $Y$ axis.

---

First question: why three angles are necessary to describe the orientation of $P$?

Suppose for a moment that $P$ is in the origin of the world frame. In order to describe the orientation of $P$, one needs only `two` axis: the third can be deducted thanks to the right-hand rule.

---

Second question: what is the correct affine transformation that transforms the coordinates $Q=(Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$ of the world frame into the coordinates $Q'=(Q_P, Q_R, Q_Y)$ into the system relative to $P$?

Using vectorial and matricial representation, $Q' = A·Q + c$ with $A$ a rotation matrix and $c$ a vector. From the known orientation of $P$ we obtain three rotation matrices: in what order should those matrices be multiplicated to obtain $A$? The correct value of $c$ is $-P$ or $-A·P$?

Comment: You are right that two axes are enough. But you need two angles to describe the direction of the first axis, and another angle to then describe the direction of the second axis.

Comment: @asgh how do you propose to represent the orientation given by rotating around the vector $(1,1,1)$ by $\pi/3$ radians using "two axis"?